# Launching an instance using aws cli gives unauthorized error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to launch an ec2 instance using aws cli but I am getting an unauthorized error. I can run start,stop,terminate commands with no issues but runInstance is failing. I have all the necessary roles attached to the ec2 instance.

Below is the policy for the role attached.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my cli command to launch an ec2 instance

```
aws --region us-east-2 ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-02e680c45XXX351e \
--subnet-id subnet-2e0254 \
--security-group-ids sg-094a23e956177 \
--count 1 \
--instance-type t2.micro \
--key-name MyOhioKeyPair \
--query "Instances[0].InstanceId" \
--tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key='Application',Value="wu-digital-eai"}]'
```

On running this command I receive an encoded error message. Below is the decoded message.

```
{
    "DecodedMessage": "{
    \"allowed\":false,\"explicitDeny\":false,\"matchedStatements\":{
    \"items\":[]},\"failures\":{\"items\":[]},\"context\":{
    \"principal\":{\"id\":\"AROAIXRNU55ISQID4PHZA:i-027f9b5ea64f\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:sts::56596531:assumed-role/LaunchInstanceTest/i-027f9b6aa64f\"},
    \"action\":\"ec2:RunInstances\",\"resource\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:55532131:network-interface/*\",\"conditions\":{\"items\":[{
    \"key\":\"ec2:Vpc\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:565532131:vpc/vpc-dc6b4\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"ec2:NetworkInterfaceID\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"*\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"aws:Resource\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"network-interface/*\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"aws:Account\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"56532131\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"ec2:AvailabilityZone\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-east-2b\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"false\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"aws:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-east-2\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"aws:Service\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"ec2\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"ec2:Subnet\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:56532131:subnet/subnet-2e54\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"aws:Type\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"network-interface\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"ec2:Region\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"us-east-2\"}]}},
    {\"key\":\"aws:ARN\",\"values\":{\"items\":[{\"value\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:56532131:network-interface/*\"}]}}]}}}"
}
```

On reading some blogs I found that this line **\"action\":\"ec2:RunInstances\"** in the above error tells the exact issue. But ec2:RunInstances policy is correctly attached to the role.

Can anyone help me in understanding what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we have to give few more privileges like - access to launch using an EC2 key pair, a security group, an Elastic Block Store (EBS) volume, and an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) in addition to Run Instance policy. Below is the json policy which resolved the issue for me.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:image/ami-*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a wonderful link from aws for the exact same issue : [Demystifying EC2 Resource-Level Permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/demystifying-ec2-resource-level-permissions/)