# Why does ec2:RunInstances permission on all resources fail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have this in a policy attached to my terraform user:

```
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                }
            }
        },
```

And the instance that I created was from the following image:

```
data "aws_ami" "amazon_linux" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.*-x86_64-gp2"]
  }
  owners = ["amazon"]
}
```

Yet, when I run terraform apply, I am getting a **ec2:RunInstances** error:

```
..."DecodedMessage": "{\"allowed\":false,\"explicitDeny\":false,\"matchedStatements\":{\"items\":[]},\"failures\":{\"items\":[]},\"context\":{\"principal\":{\"id\":\"XXXXX\",\"name\":\"terraform\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:iam::NNNN:user/terraform\"},\"action\":\"ec2:RunInstances\",\"resource\":\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:NNNN:network-interface/*\"....
```

I do have `"ec2:*ReservedInstances*"` as an explicit deny elsewhere tho, but that shouldn't cause a problem, right? Can't figure out why I can't run instances!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Basically, using `"Resources": "*"` is bad and masks problems. Made changes as follows:

1. Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112670/launching-an-instance-using-aws-cli-gives-unauthorized-error):

   - changed my `Resources` from `*` to the **full list** delineating each type of resource involved in running instances, per the SO answer.
   - removed the `Condition` regarding t2 micros
2. Based on [this blog post](https://blog.vizuri.com/limiting-allowed-aws-instance-type-with-iam-policy):

   - reinstated my condition as a separate statement targeting instances directly (i.e. `"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"`).